# run a python gui on command through a webservice e.g. FLASK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a python script(let's call it app.py) that creates a GUI for user input and runs some scripts with those inputs. I can use this locally.

I would like to host this on AWS and allow users to initiate app.py from a web service. E.g. go to a domain , select options on the GUI and click 'GO', this would run the script.

Can someone just point me in the right direction on this, please?

THanks

Comment: What part are you unsure about? You mention Flask in the title of your question. Are you running a basic Flask application yet?

Comment: So, you want to merge frontend and backend; cloud and local? If even possible it will get a large mess.

Answer (score 2):

@user1338194 
So It seems you want to create a service to run scripts ad hoc as the user wants.
What you'll need is 
1 .Server and GUI that flask + templating options can provide
2. Important decision.
  If these scripts are short lived in their running time (less than a minute or so)you can simply write them in a different file eg utils.py and run them from your flask server.

instead if these are long running tasks/scripts then you need to have some asynchronous setup.
 a) start with pushing the scripts to be run as jobs to a task queue.
 b) have a worker setup eg celery or something that executes.
 c) make sure you keep a request-id /or some identifier to track your script execution.

What you might end up needing are job queues.
https://python-rq.org/ 
http://www.celeryproject.org/ 
https://github.com/rq/Flask-RQ2 
and https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/running-background-tasks-with-flask-and-rq/ 
 
I'd recommend rq as its easier to deal with.

Comment: Then you can go on to deploy this at anywhere local or cloud or soon.